# Connection reset error after creating module content

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

After sending a POST request from the administrator module creation area, I receive a 'connection reset' error. The content is quite a large amount. Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a too much data or too much time problem. The related PHP settings are **post_max_size** or **max_execution_time**. You have to check yourself or ask your hosting provider.

Usually in the server log you can find the exact cause for the problem.

Comment: Thanks heaps Francesco! I wasnt aware of post_max_size. :)